# How Do I start multiple threads in Android in onCreate() without getting Thread Already started (IllegalThreadStateException) using for loop?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, illegalstateexception

I am performing load test of an application and have 5 threads.I want all threads to run in shuffle therefore knowing the load on the device. Suppose the number of times to run all threads is 5, then all the threads should run for 5 times successfully without IllegalThreadStateException.
I know its not correct to start a thread more than once.So How do I achieve this by using while and for loops?
I have written a sample but getting the exception.

```
int count = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    System.out.println("Loop " + i);

    try {
        th.start();
        th2.start();
        smart.start();
        fpthread.start();
        idthread.start();

        System.out.println("The count is " +count);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

edit 1: Came to know about the concept of ExecutorService framework and Threadpool and went through it. Is it possible to achieve the above scenario by using ExecutorService?
Like..

1.Creating an ExecutorService instance, 
2. fixing number of ThreadPools,
3. Creating a List Object, 
4. Using Iterator to check for next elements, 
5. adding threads to the List object and finally executing through ExecutorService object.. 
Is my thought and process correct? 
** If the way of asking my question or the procedure is wrong, Please correct me instead of downvoting as I am a newbie..

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you want to do here. Are you trying to have 5 instances of 5 types of threads running, all at the same time, for a total of 25 threads?

Comment: No. I am sorry if i didnt make it clear. Actually I am working on a device that has 4 modules like printer, fingerprint and so on.. so in each thread, I have different methods with their logics. Now I want to start all in oncreate() so that all tests can run. For once, they are running perfectly. Now I want to run them for 5 times. If I kept it in a loop,then I am getting IllegalThreadStateException. So looking for a solution. Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're doing, the only thing I can suggest is that you instantiate the threads inside the loop as well. You can only start a given thread instance once, so if you want to run a given type of thread X times then you need to create X instances of it and start each.

Comment: I read about Multithreading and I am aware of the exceptions that occur in MT. just confused of starting all threads and running them in shuffle.

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle"? Do you want to wait until all of the five threads started in the body of the loop have finished before you start the next five?

Comment: I mean all threads should run in jumbling. I know that the order of execution may vary always while running threads. I dont want to make the thread wait instead all threads should run one after other in jumble order.
suppose I have 4 threads t1,t2,t3,t4. Now If i want all threads to run for 3 times,then all t1,t2,t3,t4 should run 3 times one after another in non-sequence.

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain, but it's still not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do. Do you mean that on each run through the loop you want to start all five threads, but to do so in a random order?

Comment: yes exactly......   :)

Comment: You should be able to achieve that on each run through the loop by creating the five threads and a list, adding each of the threads to that list, shuffling the list using one of the `Collections.shuffle` methods, then iterating over the shuffled list and starting each thread.

Comment: I got it till adding each thread to the list, can you post code from shuffling the list using one of the Collections.shuffle method please?

Comment: `int count =3;   
List<Thread> listthreads=new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
 System.out.println("Loop " + i);
 try {
  th.start();
  listthreads.add(th);
  th1.start();
  listthreads.add(th1);
  smart.start();
  listthreads.add(smart);
  fpthread.start();
  listthreads.add(fpthread);
fpthread.wait(2000);
  idthread.start();
  listthreads.add(idthread);
  Collections.shuffle(listthreads);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }`
Is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry for bad format of code..

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out you can't start a thread more than once. So instead of starting the same thread on every iteration you need to create a new Thread.

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you wish to repeat the task again for some number of times.

1. Option 1[not recommended] You can create new Threads each time in the loop and then start.  Thread creation is costly and this will bring performance issues.
2. Option2. Create the thread once and start them once. Then you could have a while loop running inside each run method of the Thread (or associated Runnable) and have a volatile Flag, which you can set false to break the while loops in run method of each Thread. May be you can have sepatrate flags for each thread you create and count the iterations of the while loop. As the count becomes equal to the times you wish to execute the task you can simply decide to set the flag to false to break the loop. You could also set interrupt and check in the while loop if the Thread has been interrupted. This way you will not need a separate flag.